# Cannot pass variables to Django 3 method from HTML template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am a Django newbie who is trying to convert an existing HTML based website to Django 3.  The only complex piece of this page is a call to a Django method that uses the `django.core.mail` package and everything works, but, I am trying to pull some data off of the HTML template and pass it to this method.

The method works, only it sends a blank email. I am trying to pass contact information that the end user would fill out on the form.  If I hard code the data into the method it works.

I have tried passing the data through `urls.py`, but, everything I try fails to even parse when I call the method.  When I use a `request.GET.get` everything seems to work, just no data.

I was hoping to use something similar to JQuery like the following in the method.

```
    name = str(request.GET.get('Name:', '').strip())
    email = str(request.GET.get('Email:', '').strip())
    msg1 = str(request.GET.get('Message:', '').strip())
```

with the fields being in the HTML form.

I am going to include some of the relevant configuration items below.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

app_name = 'willdoit'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    #url(r'^contact/(?P<name>\.+)/(?P<email>\.+)/(?P<msg1>\.+)/?$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):

    name1 = request.GET.get('name', '')
    email1= request.GET.get('email', '')
    msg1 = request.GET.get('message1', '')


    subject = 'Work needed'
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    message = name + '   ' + email + '   '  + msg1
    recipient_list = ['pkustra914@gmail.com']


    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)

    return HttpResponse('Success')
```

**Relevant HTML Template section**

```
<div class="contact_content">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="contact_message wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
                      <form action="#" id="formid">
                      <form action="#" id="formid">
                  <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="name"
                placeholder="Name" required="" type="text"> </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="email" 
                 placeholder="Email" required="" type="email"> </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="Descrizione"> <label for="InserisciDescrizione"
                              class=""><b>Message</b></label> <textarea class="form-control"
                                    id="message" placeholder="Type message:" name="message1" rows="6" cols="50" 
title="Message"></textarea> </div>
            <a id="submit" href="{% url 'willdoit:contact' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
```

I would prefer to use the `request.GET.get` method, but, there is a lot more documentation passing it through the urls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `request.GET.get('Name:', '')` returns empty string when the key `'Name:'` is not found.

To fix this, use `request.GET.get('name', '')` `request.GET.get('email', '')` `request.GET.get('message', '')` instead.

---

### Details

I see that you are using a with template tag for nothing. The following line of code does not change the name attribute string to PascalCase. See *with* template tag ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with))

```
{% with Name=name Email=email Message=message %}
```

Even if it worked, your code should be calling `request.GET.get('Name', '')` instead of `request.GET.get('Name:', '')`. But it won't work, as with would not modify the attribute names in the GET request.

---

### #EDIT1

There are apparently more bugs in your html code. I have reformatted your code and listed up some obvious bugs.

```
<!--REFORMATTED CODE-->
<form action="#" id="formid"> <--------------DUPLICATES, remove one
<form action="#" id="formid"> <--------------DUPLICATES, remove one
  <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="name"
      placeholder="Name" required="" type="text"> </div>
  <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="email" 
      placeholder="Email" required="" type="email"> </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="Descrizione">
      <label for="InserisciDescrizione" class=""><b>Message</b></label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message"
          placeholder="Type message:" name="message1" rows="6" cols="50" 
          title="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <a id="submit" href="{% url 'willdoit:contact' %}"
        class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
  <-------- MISSING DIV END TAG
<-------- MISSING FORM END TAG
```

Furthermore, you are calling the server by url directly using the following code:

```
<a id="submit" href="{% url 'willdoit:contact' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
```

This does not tell the page which form you want to submit (there are cases where there are multiple forms).

You have two choices:

1. Replace the  tag with standard html form submit button `<input type="submit">`, and add the url to the action attribute of the form. Use the following code to do so:

   ```
    <form action="{% url 'willdoit:contact' %} id="formid">
      ...
        ...
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
   ```

   This solution will by default use the GET method to send a request to the server, and you will be able to get the inputted values by calling `request.GET.get(name)`.
2. If you are using JQuery, you can replace the  with the following:

   ```
   <a href="{% url 'willdoit:contact' %}" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Submit</a>
   ```

   This is however not recommended. Please use the standard html form input tag for the submit button.

Comment: I made the edits and am still getting an empty email.  I also stripped out some of the ad hoc pieces that made there way in.  ** views.py ** `    name1 = request.GET.get('name', '')
    email1= request.GET.get('email', '')
    msg1 = request.GET.get('message1', '')`  It looks like I have a small buffer, but, I also edited the html to strip out the { with } and renamed the variable to message1.  
`

Comment: Never mind.  I edited my question to the current configuration.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Tell me if it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Great.  Moving the method call to the form tag worked great.
Thanks! You guys are the best.